# Regex (Ruby) to capture object name and id number

Tags: html, ruby, regex

For example I have two potential markups:

```
<iframe src="http://embed.app.com/packages/495" width="850" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

<iframe src="https://embed.app.com/videos/10332?hide_text=1&amp;buy_btn=0&amp;autoplay=0" width="960" height="540" class="responsive-embed"></iframe>
```

And I'm looking to use Ruby match whether it's for a `video` or a `package` as well as its `:id` number

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what programming language (the regex)?

Comment: Only use regex once you have used an XML parser. Otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1916721

Comment: Does `:id` means **495** and **10332**

Comment: @chhhris you mean this http://www.rubular.com/r/XFqMeXdWZv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 supports `\K`. So you could use the below regex,

```
<iframe src="https?:\/\/[^\s]*?\/\K(?:videos|packages)\/\d+
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/FX6yCOZVEQ)

OR

If you don't want to match the id's then use this,

```
<iframe src="https?:\/\/[^\s]*?\/\K(?:videos|packages)
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/XFqMeXdWZv)

OR

This would capture the both in two separate groups.

```
<iframe src="https?:\/\/[^\s]*?\/\K(videos|packages)\/(\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/MAFQLCjPeR)

Comment: That last one is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*?\/(?=packages|videos).*?\/(\d+)
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/1

Comment: kudos so far, that matches the ID numbers... if I didn't know which html I was parsing, how would I match if it's a `Video` or a `Package`? Sorry I'm horrible at regex and on a deadline. Thanks!

Comment: @chhhris just add them as well.`(?=packages|videos|Video|Package)` and you are ready to roll

Comment: thanks @vks, to clarify, i meant between the two example markups, how can I get the match value to equal either `packages` or `videos` instead of the `:id`. For example I got this working: http://rubular.com/r/HJ6TxYpOEO

Comment: @chhhris didnt get you.You already have the match of `video` and `package`.you want both `video` `id`?

Comment: @chhhris Try 
`^.*?\/(?=packages?|videos?).*?\/(\d+)`

Answer (score 2):

An example with nokogiri to find the src attributes in iframe tags and a pattern to extract informations:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_doc = <<EOD
<iframe src="http://embed.app.com/packages/495" width="850" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://embed.app.com/videos/10332?hide_text=1&amp;buy_btn=0&amp;autoplay=0" width="960" height="540" class="responsive-embed"></iframe>
EOD

puts "Type         ID\n----------------------"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_doc)
srcList = doc.xpath('//iframe/@src')
srcList.each do |src| 
    if ( m = src.to_s.match(/\/(?<type>packages|videos)\/(?<id>[0-9]+)/) )
        printf("%-12s %s\n",m[:type], m[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use regex once you have used an XML parser. Otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1916721.

Once you get just the src attribute you can parse the link with this quick regex:

```
https?:\/\/embed\.app\.com\/((?:packages)|(?:videos))\/([0-9]+)
```

You will then get either `packages` or `videos` in the 1st capture group (you can trim the `s` as you please. In the 2nd capture group you will get the `id`.

For an example see here: http://regex101.com/r/uF4bI1/2

Comment: If you're already employing an XML parser then why not throw in URI or Addressable to parse the URL?

Comment: @muistooshort They asked for regex so I gave them regex. That would probably be the better option though good point

Answer (score 0):

in ruby, Regex is

```
/iframe src="http:\/\/[^\/]+\/[packages|videos]+\/([^"]+)"/
```